# Option -o in driver_opts in Docker-compose.yml file

Tags: docker-compose, docker-volume

I have a specific question :

Can someone explain me what is the option 'o' (usually used with 'bind' value) in driver_opts section of a volume in a docker-compose file ?
I searched on the Internet but I found no answer.